# Absolute Positioning inside a DIV

Tags: css, positioning

Hi im having a problem where i cant get two images positioned within a div (see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edddotcom/naEFm/)

i want the two triangles/arrows (class "triangle") to be at the top right and bottom right of the dark grey grey div (id "main")

I need all the other elements positioned as they are (the menu on the left and main content on the right

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul class="slidingMenu">
                <li><a href="#">LINK1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <div id="content">
                <img id="mainimg" src="http://onlyhdwallpapers.com/wallpaper/ball_monochrome_desktop_1680x1050_hd-wallpaper-183077.jpg"/>
            <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
            </div>
            <div class="structure">
            <img id="up" class="triangle" src="http://f0.bcbits.com/z/26/17/2617229726-1.jpg"/>
            <img id="down" class="triangle" src="http://f0.bcbits.com/z/26/17/2617229726-1.jpg"/>
            <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background:#292929;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#page{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
#container{
    display:block;
    background-color:red;
    width:900px;
    height:400px;
    text-align:center;
}
#menu{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:white;
    width:40%;
    overflow:none;
    float:left;
}
ul{
    list-style:none;
    text-align:right;
}
ul a{
    font-size:50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-right:10px;
    color: #ddd;
}
ul a:hover{
    background-color:#999967;
}
#main{
    background-color:grey;
    width:60%;
    float:right;
    max-height:330px;
}
#mainimg{
    width:40%;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    max-height:300px;
}
#main p{
    text-align:justify;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
#content{
    max-height:250px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
.structure{
    display:block;
    height:40px;
    background-color:white;
    width:20px;
}
#up{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
}
#down{
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
}
```

If you could edit the jsfiddle with what you think is best that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to #main:

```
#main {
    background-color:grey;
    width:60%;
    float:right;
    max-height:400px;
    position:relative;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/naEFm/1/)**

Comment: Beat me to it!  Explanation: `display:absolute` will be positioned within the bounds of the first parent container it finds with `position:absolute` or `position:relative`

Answer (score 0):

you need to `position:relative;` the arrow images, so that they will stay with in the `#main` div, see the `position:relative;` tells the browser that the arrows must be positioned relative to the main div, "or watever div its directly in", (otherwise the `position:absolute;` will be positioned relative to the whole `<body>` tag automatically. Hope this helps you understand the problem peace!